# Is there a TSQL command or another way to rename AOAG (Always On Availability Group)?

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

We have an AOAG named with "space" and I need to rename it to not have "spaces". It was created before my time. The 3rd party vendor tool does not work with AOAG that has spaces. There are about 40 databases in the AOAG (SharePoint).

The property is greyed out in SSMS. Is there another option? As this is production, I am looking for a solution with minimal downtime.

Thanks much,
Debbie

Comment: I've never tried it but have you tried sp_rename?

Comment: Thanks, I see it as a cluster resource and it allows me to rename the cluster resource using failover cluster manager. I did not make the change since its production. I wonder if someone has tried this. Thanks,

Comment: Be extremely cautious with AGs and the Failover Cluster Manager. AGs were designed to be manipulated with T-SQL / PowerShell only. Messing with the AG cluster resources manually is only for advanced experts. To quote Brent Ozar, "beware, there be dragons."

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is a way to rename it (safely). You will need to rebuild the AG.

If you do it during an outage window where you can eliminate or minimize data changes then you should be able to do it without having to perform new backups / restores.